# Add a dynamic content to a same place in print in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I use the following code to append a dynamic content to printing the content to an A4 paper in html.

```
  $('#result_body').append(

                      '<div id=result_signature'+count+' class="footer" 
                       style="position: fixed;bottom:20px; right:20px">'+
                      '<p>'+data[count].signature+'</p>'+

                      '<br>'+

                      '</div>'
                      )
                      
                      $('#result_body').append( '<div class="pagebreak"> </div>')
```

My problem is, when I run this, If there are two different signatures, it prints both signatures in all pages and if there is only one signature it prints only one (which is correct) in all pages. But if i set the position to relative, it prints the signatures correctly, but not to the bottom of the page. I used the fixed position as i need to print the signatures at the bottom of the every page, regardless of the content is extending to multiple pages.

Is there any way to append the signatures to the bottom of the printing pages other than using the fixed position?

(Both signatures look same for demo purpose)

When position is relative

[image]

[image]

When position is Fixed

[image]

All I want is the both signature at bottom correctly.

Comment: Why are you adding a page break to the end?

Comment: @hanut I want to append the next data to the next page on print. Data is populated by a loop and an Ajax call.

Comment: If position fixed is working, what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: @hanut if the position is fixed, both signatures prints on both pages. I need print only the relevant signature in the relevant page bottom. It seems the position is fixed to the browser window not to the printing page, therefore the fixed div is attaching to the both signatures to the both pages.